# Layers not reappearing in composer after restarting QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, print-composer

I would like to create several maps in QGIS, each showing various elements.  Layers and their styles are locked and in the same CRS.

Here is the rendering when I save the document before quitting:
[image]

And here is what I got upon reopening the document:
[image]

So how can I lock the OSM background? I'm using QGIS 2.18.7 and the layer uses the QuickMapServices plugin.

Comment: which version of QGIS? Also, are you using the OpenLayers plugin for the basemap layer, or QuickMapServices?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18.7 and QuickMapServices